# Appengine non-interactive remote script

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I just learned that I can use `remote_api_shell.py` to run commands on my remote applications interactively.

I would like to use that ability to create local scripts that generate reports with data from the remote database.

I was expecting to be able to run a command like:

`remote_api_shell.py my-app-id --script usageReport.py`

But I don't see any options in remote_api_shell.py that will take a python script as input.
Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think it's possible you should probably feature request this, this will make a lot of things awesomer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I thought this was interesting I made one too here:

https://gist.github.com/faisalraja/6136087

Just replace

```
GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE_SDK = None # with your sdk path
# unless you are running with it included
```

Then run your scripts with:

```
./remote_api_script.py -r usageReport.py --email "email@example.com" --password "****" app-id
```

It accepts exactly same params as the remote_api_shell.py

Comment: Thanks, it's working. I just replaced this line: `GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE_SDK = os.getenv('GAE_SDK')` since that environment variable is already supposed to exist.

Answer (score 1):

here ya go man, about to save your life.. plugin in the contents from this gist: https://gist.github.com/gregorynicholas/6084846

Comment: interesting! wll test it and let you know